# I'm using this.$router.push to navigate programmatically, however, I'm being sent to wrong URL and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using nested routes so that might be causing the issue, however, I'm not sure how to fix it. I have the following route and children routes:

```
{
    path: '/summoner/:summonerName',
    component: Summoner,
    children: [
        { path: '', component: Matchlist },
        { path: '/match/:matchId', component: SpecificMatch, name: 'specificMatch' }
    ]
},
```

When I'm on path `/summoner/:summonerName` I want to see the default Summoner parent component and the `Matchlist` component and when I'm on path `/summoner/:summonerName/match/:matchId` I want to see the default Summoner parent and the `specificMatch` child component. This works fine, however, when I try to use:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'specificMatch', params: { summonerName: this.summoner, matchId: matchId, summonerInfo: this.summonerInfo, match: match}})
```

I get sent to `/match/:matchId` path instead of `/summoner/:summonerName/match/:matchId` which breaks the component because the components needs to get the username from the path. I assumed `this.$router.push` would send me to the correct path, alas no. Any tips how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It's a matter of absolute and relative paths.

Your route with the name `'specificMatch'` has the specified absolute path `'/match/:matchId'` so this is where you are navigated to. If you wish to append your path to the path of your parent route you will have to make your path relative, which means to leave out the initial slash (`/`) - e.i. `path: 'match/:matchId'`.